# How to fill DataTable column with data from list of struct?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

**BACKGROUND**

I have simple struct:

```
public struct PostCode
{
    public long itemId;
    public string postCode;

    public PostCode(long id, string code)
    {
        this.itemId = id;
        this.postCode = code;
    }
}
```

This struct is used as record template.

Im using it to store data from some web service.

I need to join these codes with data stored already in DataTable.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("postCode", Type.GetType("System.String")));
 // more columns here

 // getRecords returns datatable but postCode field is empty
 // DataTable dt can contain 100-10000 records
 dt = getRecords(); 

 // preparing list of identifiers (same record count)
 List<long> listOfId = getDataIds(dt);

 // preparing list of identifiers with postal codes
 List<PostCode> codeList = getListOfPostCodes(listOfId);

 // filling postal code field in datatable
 // TODO: code I'm asking for goes here
```

This is not SQL database, data comes from web service and only few methods are exposed. It's impossible to join data on server side or query for all data with postal code.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How I can join my List with DataTable object?
2. Maybe I should get rid of this PostCode struct and use another DataTable instead?

Comment: Did the answer below help you, or do you specifically need a C# 2.0 solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
        {
            d["postCode"] = from y in codeList
                             where y.itemId == (int)d["id"]
                             select new { PostCode = y.postCode };
        }
```

Fill the postCode in the datatable from the list using a quick linq statement.  Also, the id is a long on one side and an int on the other, if it is storing similar data, you should keep the sizes the same.

Comment: This answer uses LINQ but the question is tagged [tag:c#-2.0]